# Geolocation with javascript

Tags: javascript, geolocation, usability

I'm building a website with a geolocation function. It shows a user points of interests around them. Everything works fine, but the usability should be smoother.
At the end I have a button. If a user clicks the button, it opens a new website with the POIs. Therefore I have two key questions:

- 1) WHEN should I ask the browser (with javascript) for the latitude
  and longitude?
- 1a) Should I implement this in every page respectively in my layout
  that I have this information permanently? I could load a javascript
  which loads the data in a hidden form on every page. if the button is
  pressed, the form will be sent as post or get.
- 1b) If the button is clicked, a blank page loads the javascript to
  get the position and calls after the POIs-Page. Could take a little
  bit a longer time to load two pages from the server with javascript
  between.
- 2) What is common around geolocation to pass the geodata to a
  website? (Both would work for me)
- 2a) With GET in the url
- 2b) With POST via a (hidden) form?

I'm looking forward to hearing from you about best practice. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can answer one of the questions: If the location and points of interest change in the transition between pages then you need implement that each page individually, otherwise, I think you can do this once (maybe on Load) and save the information in session to transfer it between the pages.